# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' when reading .CSV file in directory

Tags: python, string, file, directory

I have a program that reads the first .CSV file in a given directory.
However, at the end of my program it gives an error on line 9 reading unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'.

I'm unsure why this happens when firstfile is called exactly 18949a_2020110-02_QUVA_1400hr_ABS_BC_AS0001.CSV

The program is given below:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 

fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test")
folder_walk = os.walk(fileDir)
first_file_in_folder = next(folder_walk)[2][0]
firstfile = first_file_in_folder.replace(" ","_") #Just adds hyphens to the string name
data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test"/firstfile) #Reads the .CSV file but gives the error
```

Thanks

Comment: `"C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test"` is a string, `firstfile` is a string, and `/` outside of a string is a division operator. Python thinks you are trying to divide strings mathematically. Try doing string concatenation with `+`, `str.format()` syntax, or using an f-string to join the variable to the string

Comment: @G.Anderson, Thanks mate it works now!

Answer (score 1):

You have this line of code here: `data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test/"/firstfile)`.

Your issue is with the `/firstfile`, because python ends up trying to divide "C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test" by the string variable, 'firstfile'.

Change the last line to `data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test/"+firstfile)`, so it adds the strings together instead of dividing them.